# user or profile tab icon is not visible

Tags: mobile, extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am new to sencha touch and want to have three tabs icons i.e. `Home, Profile/User and Camera`. The `home` icon is currently visible but `Profile/User` is not. How can I add icon of `profile/user` and `camera` to tab in sencha touch?

here is my code for Profile.js

```
Ext.define('find.view.Profile' , {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'profile',

config: {
    title: 'Profile',
    iconCls: 'user',
    layout: 'fit',
    scrollable: true,
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    styleHtmlCls: 'profilepage',
    html: ['<h1>Profile</h1>'].join('')
}
});
```

Comment: Are you using a tabpanel as parent?

Comment: Well now user is working fine. But I am struggling with camera icon. Could you please tell me what is the class name for camera? I am trying these classes `cam, camera, photo, pic, picture` but none of them are working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of `pictos`. Before that you need to install `Ruby`, as well as `Sass` and `Compass`. Follow this tutorial to adding new icon mask:

http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/styling-user-interface-sencha-touch-application

Answer (score 2):

All the icons you can use in your ST app are located into the directory

```
resources/themes/images/default/pictos
```

However, not all are included by default in your application theme.
In order to include those additional icons you need to include the line

```
@include pictos-iconmask(<YOUR_ICON>);
```

In your app.scss file and then compile the theme using COMPASS.
If you are not familiar at all with Sencha Touch, I strongly suggest you to take a look at the following video from SenchaCon 2011 on how to style ST apps.

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/video/theming

PS: Please notice that the "pictos-iconmask" mixin works only on ST < 2.2.0.alpha because from this version, it has been deprecated because of the integration of the [Pictos Font](http://pictos.cc/font/).

Comment: I am using sencha touch 2.1 and there is not theme folder inside resources folder.

Comment: Then something is messed out! The folder is "themes" and not "theme". Download again the ST SDK, extract it, and you'll see the mentioned folder.

Answer (score 0):

Camera is not available as iconCls. The following icons are supported ([seen here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Button)):

```
action
add
arrow_down
arrow_left
arrow_right
arrow_up
bookmarks
compose
delete
download
favorites
home
info
locate
maps
more
organize
refresh
reply
search
settings
star
team
time
trash
user
```

For styling your own icon look at `@Andrea Cammarata` and `@user1479606` answers

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add custom icon(which are not listed in pictos ) use this css in place of somename name use your name for icon

`.x-tab .x-button-icon.somename,.x-button .x-button-icon.x-icon-mask.somename{-webkit-mask-image:url('path-to-image/facebook-icon.png')}`

and use it as

```
iconCls: 'somename',
```